# R quantmod: how to plot bar charts with >day granularity?

Tags: r, quantmod

With this code there is a "candlestick" for each day. What is the proper way to modify either getSymbols() or chartSeries() to have a larger granularity? eg. weekly, monthly, quarterly?

```
library(quantmod)
getSymbols("AAPL")
chartSeries(AAPL, type="candlestick", subset="last 12 months")
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

try this for weekly data:

```
v <- to.weekly(AAPL)   chartSeries(v, type="candlestick", subset="last 12 months")
```

or for monthly:

```
m <- to.monthly(AAPL)  chartSeries(m, type="candlestick", subset="last 12 months")
```

or for quarterly:

```
q <- to.quarterly(AAPL) ; chartSeries(q, type="candlestick", subset="last 10 years")
```